# Why cant we assign a subclass object to an object of it's superclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

Sub extends Sandwich. A is Sub "is a" Sandwich, but Sandwich "is not a" Sub.

So why then does the generalization `y=x` (essentially `sub` equals `sandwich`) throw an error, but the specialization `x=y` (`sandwich` equals `sub`), work?

```
public class Sandwich {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sandwich x = new Sandwich();
        Sub y = new Sub();
        y=x;
    }

}
```

here is the `Sub` class:

```
public class Sub extends Sandwich {}
```

Comment: No, your understanding is wrong.

Comment: alright then. How so. Please elaborate.

Comment: If Cat extends Animal, then each cat is an animal, but not each animal is a cat.

Comment: thats exactly how I understand it. But the error is showing the opposite.

Comment: `y=x` means "I have a sandwich, please treat it like a sub", which does't work if `x` is actually a panini.  `x=y` means "I have a sub, please treat it like a sandwich", which is no problem.

Comment: No it doesn't.  Not each Sandwich is a Sub. So if you know that yours is then you need to perform an explicit cast.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I was approaching it like I can turn a sub into a sandwich. Since all subs are sandwiches. This makes sense thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y=x` means "I have a sandwich, please treat it like a sub", which does't work if what I have is actually a panini.

`x=y` means "I have a sub, please treat it like a sandwich", which is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is your own question.

> my understanding is Sub "is a" Sandwich, but Sandwich "is not a" Sub.

**Sub "is a" Sandwich**
This means that you can treat `y` (a Sub object) as a `Sandwich` and reference it with a `Sandwich` variable: `x = y` (because `Sub` is a `Sandwish`)

**Sandwich "is not a" Sub**
In de other hand, you can't treat `x` (a Sandwish object) as a `Sub` and you can't reference it with a `Sub` variable: `y = x` ERROR (because `Sandwish` is not a `Sub`)

I hope help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the `Sub` class as always something more functional than the `Sandwich` class, because `Sub` **extends** `Sandwich`. That is, if the `Sub` class was declaring a new method and `y=x;` was compiled without an error, how could you call `y.newMethod()` when that object simply doesn't have it? This is why the `y=x;` assignment in your code can't be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

`Sandwich` is more general type than `Sub` type. 
`Sub` is more spesific type than `Sandwich` type.
The sub class has more features in addition to the parent class features.

`Parent = Sub
x = y`

You can assign a sub class reference to a parent class reference and 
this is about `polymorphism`. Every `sub` is a `sandwich`. Because parent class’ interface supports sub class’ interface.

But you can’t assign a parent class reference to a sub class reference. Because `Sub` type is more specific than `Sandwich` type and every sandwich is not a Sub.